# False proof that every holomorphic function is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function. We know that $f$ is infinitely differentiable. Then its laplacian is defined by $\Delta f(x+iy) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(f(x+iy)) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(f(x+iy))$. Since $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(f(x+iy)) = f''(x+iy)$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(f(x+iy)) = i^2 f''(x+iy) = -f''(x+iy)$, we have that $$\Delta f(x+iy) = 0$$
Since not all holomorphic functions are harmonic, where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that holomorphic functions aren't harmonic?

Comment: I have done some research and I found this equality for holomorphic functions $$\Delta f = 4\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}f$$ If the left side is always 0, I don't understand the interest of this identity.

Comment: @ArthurBreton that identity isn't just true for holomorphic functions; it's true for all smooth functions of a complex variabe. in the holomorphic case, $f$ is in the kernel of $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}$ and so the right hand side is 0.

Comment: I see, thank you very much !

Comment: I think you should answer this question yourself and close it.

Comment: I will definitively do so, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the proof is right, every holomorphic functions are harmonic.